# Most acceptable way to show hyper link file type to the web page user?

Tags: usability, hyperlink, icon

I want to show the user that a **hyperlink links to a PDF file** (or Word/PowerPoint etc.).

Here are some methods I've considered:

> [Farming Report (PDF)](http://about:blank)
>
> [Farming Report (PDF, 52K)](http://about:blank)

Alternatively, I've thought about using icons:

[image]
[image]

(Examples from these pages:
[Making hyperlink icons with CSS](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/08/making-hyperlink-icons-with-css/#more-787),
[Showing hyperlink cues with CSS](http://askthecssguy.com/articles/showing-hyperlink-cues-with-css/#post-56))

**What's the accepted, standard and accessible way of doing this?** Are there any guidelines available somewhere?

Comment: I like this format - "Farming Report (PDF, 52K)" without any icons. It makes the file type evident even in low-bandwith scenarios or when viewed through mobile devices.

Comment: I'd second that. The inclusion of information on the size of the file can have a big difference on whether (or simply when) people choose to download it as well, so that's really useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard and accepted way of doing this.

Your examples are good ways to accomplish this. An alternative is to show a PDF icon after the link to indicate it links to a PDF document. You'll see many sites doing the same thing with external links. The page you linked to shows good examples of this. [This page](http://pooliestudios.com/projects/iconize/) provides lots of icons you can use.

Comment: Interesting - you've used my second example page.

Comment: Indeed I did. I think that's a good indication that it is a good resource.

Comment: Fair enough! :)